# Spnego setup with websphere custom SSOAuthentication

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, spnego

I am trying to setup Websphere with Spnego. I have my custom SSOAuthentication implementation (the application needs to run o several different web servers). The problem i am facing is that the spnego-client configuration is being searched in
wsjaas.conf file, while i have it setup in a custom conf file. Is there a way to use my custom .conf file and not the wsjaas.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this by editing a system launch properties file /AppServer/properties/systemlaunch/base/.systemlaunch.properties

There you have configured the java.security.auth.login.config